# How might I control a checkbox in a repeater?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, checkbox, repeater

In my project, there is a `Repeater`. And in the repeater is a `CheckBox`. When I bind data to the `Repeater`, how can I control (set checked / unchecked) the `CheckBox`s that are produced by the `Repeater`?

This is what I've tried:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Security1" runat="server">

  <ItemTemplate>

    <tr>
      <td> <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server"> </td>

      <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Featurename") %></td>
    </tr>

  </ItemTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Indicating what language you talk about (at least in the tags) can be useful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this ;

```
< asp:repeater id="repeater" runat="server">
  < li>< asp:checkbox id="chkbx" runat="server />
  < %#Eval("attribute_name_here")%>< /li>
< /asp:repeater>
```

Code behind , adding properties to checkboxes ;

```
protected void repeater_ItemDataBound(...)
{
  if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
      e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
      ((CheckBox)e.Item.FindControl("chkbx")).Attributes
       .Add("project_id",
        ((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem)["project_id"].ToString());
    }
}
```

Then when you want to check them ; you can also check attribute in if of course

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in repeater.Items)
{
  CheckBox chkbx = item.FindControl("chkbx") as CheckBox;
  if (chkbx.Checked)
  {
    Response.Write("Checked Project: " + 
      chkbx.Attributes["project_id"].ToString() + "< br />");
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm glad it did :) Kolay Gelsin.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that 'Featurename' is a bit/bool value, so if you want to control the 'checked' state you would bind it to the 'Checked' property of the checkbox control:

Something like this...

```
<asp:checkbox id="check1" runat="server" Checked='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Featurename") %>'/>
```